# Should I add .idea/sshConfigs.xml to gitignore?

Tags: git, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am using JetBrains IDEs and build git repo on the project root folder. While the [JetBrains website](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) offers some suggestions but nothing on this specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at this file I see my configured server host name, port and username.

No password is included but I believe these information should as well be avoided in public git repo to prevent social engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of personal preference, but the JetBrains documentation says the following (emphasis mine):

> Select the checkbox to restrict the use of the SSH configuration to the current project. Such SSH configuration cannot be reused outside the current project. It does not appear in the list of available configurations in other projects.
>
> **The SSH configurations are stored in the .idea directory together with the project, which allows sharing them between team members through a VCS.**
>
> When the checkbox is cleared, the SSH configuration is visible in all CLion projects. Its settings can be reused across several projects.

You can read the full article [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/settings-tools-ssh-configurations.html#ssh-connection-parameters).

I guess that these files are meant to be shared. Also, when generating a `gitignore` through the handy [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) website, I don't see this specific file to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I think this file should definitely be added to .gitgnore. It contains too much information that can potentially be used against your and your projects.

When I found that this file is not ignored by default, as well as `webServers.xml` I decided not to tempt fate and add the whole `.idea` folder to `.gitignore`. It doesn't seem for me so important to keep IDE settings in the repository.